# How to restrict visibility of classes to specific other classes?

Tags: c++

Is there a way in C++ (03 or 11) to restrict visibility of a class (similar to the default or package scope in Java)? For example:

`Foo` should be visible only to `Bar` but not to `Baz`.

```
class Foo {};
class Bar { Foo foo; /* OK */ };
class Baz { Foo foo; /* not visible, error */ };
```

The anonymous namespace solution suggested here [How to restrict the visibility of a class outside the namespace in which it is declared?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9858754/how-to-restrict-the-visibility-of-a-class-outside-the-namespace-in-which-it-is-d) does not seem to be working. [ Demo: http://ideone.com/fsEKPu ] Have I misunderstood anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want `Foo` only to be visible to `Bar`, then just make `Foo` a private nested class inside `Bar`.

```
class Bar
{
  public:

  private:
  class Foo { };
};
```

This way only `Bar` (and any class declared a `friend` of `Bar`) can access `Bar::Foo`.

Comment: Well, unfortunately, it is not *only* `Bar`, but `Bar1` and `Bar2`. It is not a big problem leaving them visible, but I prefer not to give the client code anything that it does not need.

Comment: If you want another class, like `Bar2` to have access to `Bar::Foo`, you can use the `friend` keyword: `friend class Bar2`.  This way, only "friends" of `Bar` can access `Bar::Foo` or other private fields.

Comment: That solution is certainly usable, but I was wondering if there is a cleaner way to do it. `friend` would expose all private members of `Bar1` to `Bar2` as well.

Answer (score 0):

If it's possible to have Bar and Baz class definitions in different cpp files, you define Foo in the same file where Bar is (or Bar1 and Bar2 are) present and have Foo enclosed under anonymous namespace.